# Como puedo ocultar el subitem de un item de un menuStrip en vb?

Tags: vb.net

Como puedo ocultar un subitem de un item de un menu (menuStrip) en `vb`

intente con este pero me dice que esta fuera de intervalo

```
MenuStrip1.Items.Item(1).Enabled = False
```

Intente con este codigo y me oculta es el menu completo

```
MenuStrip1.Items(0).Visible = False
```

Comment: `MenuStrip1.Items(0).Visible = False` yo probé con este y funciona.

Comment: a mi me desaparece todo el menu @JorgeArturoJuarez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu IDE te muestra el nombre de tu ítem en el área de propiedades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso mi item se llama

```
ToolStripMenuItem6
```

ahora solo accede a su propiedad visible:

```
ToolStripMenuItem6.Visible = False
```

Answer (score -1):

Los Menus y submenus tienen su propiedad `Name` y puedes acceder a ellos directamente. Pongamos que tienes un Menu llamado `Menu1` y debajo un submenu llamado `Submenu1`. Para ocultar el submenú simplemente tienes que hacer:

```vb
Submenu1ToolStripMenuItem.Visible=false
```

Normalmente por defecto el nombre es el texto del menu + `ToolStripMenuItem`, pero puedes modificarlo a lo que quieras.

**Edit**

Te doy un par de opciones mas por si lo que quieres es ocultar un submenu con respecto al menu padre:

```vb
'Oculta el primer submenu con respecto al menu llamado Menu1ToolStripMenuItem
CType(Me.MenuStrip1.Items("Menu1ToolStripMenuItem"), ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Cast(Of ToolStripMenuItem).ElementAt(0).Visible = False

'Oculta el submenu llamado Submenu1ToolStripMenuItem del Menu1ToolStripMenuItem
CType(Me.MenuStrip1.Items("Menu1ToolStripMenuItem"), ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Cast(Of ToolStripMenuItem).Where(Function(s) s.Name = "Submenu1ToolStripMenuItem").FirstOrDefault().Visible = False
```

Comment: Me dice que el cast no es miembtro de ToolSTripItemCollection @pikoh

Comment: Hmm..que raro. Que version de .net framework estas usando?